# Erase elements in a nested map

Tags: c++, dictionary, nested, erase

I would like to be able to remove an element but I don't know what I am missing. The programa crashes.

```
void Movies::removePeliculaAlies(short unsigned year,string title){
    map<string,map<unsigned short, string> >::iterator itAlies=_mapaAlies.begin();
    while(itAlies!=_mapaAlies.end()){
        map<unsigned short,string>::iterator itInterior;
        itInterior=itAlies->second.find(year);
        if(itInterior!=itAlies->second.end()){
            if(title==itInterior->second){
                itAlies->second.erase(itInterior);->>>>>>>>>>>>>NOT WORKING WHY?
            }
            if(itAlies->second.size()==0) _mapaAlies.erase(itAlies->first);
        }
        itAlies++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say, "NOT WORKING WHY?" ... but what does it do?  Does it do nothing?  Does it crash?

Comment: Yes the program it crash

Comment: Well perhaps you could try debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

The crash may be caused by this code:

```
    if(itAlies->second.size()==0) _mapaAlies.erase(itAlies->first);
}
itAlies++;
```

In here you are editing `_mapaAlies` and right after that you do `itAlies++;` even though the iterator `itAlies` was invalidated by the edit.

Instead you could try first making the increment and then deleting the element

```
    if(itAlies->second.size()==0){
        map<string,map<unsigned short, string> >::iterator oldIter = itAlies; // copy the iterator
        ++itAlies;                 // increment the iterator
        _mapaAlies.erase(oldIter); // erase the copy
        continue;                  // skip the incrementing in the end
    }
}
itAlies++;
```

In general you should be vary of editing a container while looping through it as editing may invalidate the iterators and cause crashes or possibly worse.

Comment: `erase` returns an iterator to just after the erased element, so you can do this without creating a copy by just using `itAlies = _mapAlies.erase(itAlies);`.  You still need the `continue;` to avoid incrementing the iterator a second time.

Comment: @ChrisDodd According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/) the new iterator is returned after C++11 which the asker might not be using.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar problem in my own code.  I don't think the crash has anything to do with the fact that you have a map within a map.  I think the problem is more likely related to the fact that you delete an element of the map while iterating over the same map.

I solved this problem in my own code as follows: I iterate over the map, and if I erase any map elements I will raise a boolean flag and break my iteration loop.  After the loop, if that flag is raised, I will restart the iteration and repeat until there are no more erasures necessary.  Here is my code:

```
void serve::reclaim_server_resources()
{
    dPrintf("()");

    bool erased = false;

    for (std::map<int, serve_client>::iterator iter = client_map.begin();
         iter != client_map.end(); ++iter) {
        if (!iter->second.check()) {
            dPrintf("erasing idle client...");
            client_map.erase(iter->first);
            /* stop the loop if we erased any targets */
            erased = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* if we erased a target, restart the above by re-calling this function recursively */
    if (erased)
        reclaim_server_resources();
}
```

If I remove the `break;` from my loop, the code crashes, probably in the same way that yours does.

This is really just a suggestion for a workaround to your problem.  Perhaps there might be better solutions available, but it should be helpful, at least, to know how similar problems can manifest in other similar situations.

If you want to try my workaround yourself, you might want to break your function up into two smaller functions, so that when you restart the iteration by recursively calling the new function, it can restart the iteration of the internal map rather that restarting the entire external map.